# A word for a question that can be easily answered

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What do we call a question the answer to which seems obvious to many of us?

Comment: Duh!! ..........

Comment: Do you mean a question with an obvious answer that is asked for some other reason, perhaps for a hidden agenda or for two no-win answers?

Comment: *self-evident* is another option.

Comment: @YosefBaskin No. Just a question that its answer is obvious.

Comment: A "no-brainer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [no-brainer](https://www.lexico.com/definition/no-brainer).

Adding the requisite number of characters.

Comment: So this answer, no-brainer, is the best and its meaning is *Adding the requisite number of characters.* ;))

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, my answer was just "It's a no-brainer" but a valid answer must be 30 characters or more, so I added "Adding the requisite number of characters" to pad my answer out.

Answer (score 3):

> Rhetorical question - A question asked in order to create a dramatic
>   effect or to make a point rather than to get an answer.
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rhetorical_question)

If the answer isn't obvious then the question isn't rhetorical.

Comment: Let me add that teachers and preachers ask rhetorical questions so the listeners think about the answer for themselves and own the answer in the process. It's a staple in the art of effective speaking.

Comment: If an interviewer asks an interviewee a series of easy ("softball") questions (because the interviewer and interviewee are friends, because the interviewer doesn't know enough about the subject to ask tough questions, etc.), then many people would not necessarily call those questions rhetorical.

Answer (score 3):

The perfect word would be *softball*, as defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/softball_question):

> *North American*
> A question that is easy to answer; an unchallenging question.

Answer (score 1):

An *obvious question* is the most common phrase - really!  The phrase could also refer to a question which rather obviously poses itself in the course of the discussion in question as well.

You could also call it a *trivial question*, although that implies a lack of importance.

Comment: Most common in what context? Do you have any sources for that?

Comment: @KevinWorkman But when you say, for example, that "the question is obvious", it means that the question itself, and not the answer, is obvious.